# What does the command '$FAVerbose = 0' do in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc, wolfram-physics

I have seen this right below the "<<FeynCalc`" command that loads FeynCalc.

`$LoadAddOns={"FeynArts"}; <<FeynCalc`;
`$FAVerbose=0;`

I assumed this suppresses the text output that acknowledges the makers of FeynCalc. But that isn't the case.

Comment: Set it to 1 instead of zero and find out what is verbosely output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `$FAVerbose` is about how verbose the `FeynArts` will put out messages from functions that tell you their progress:

1. `$FAVerbose=0` suppress the progress messages from functions entirely;
2. `$FAVerbose=1` put out only summaries;
3. `$FAVerbose=2` (default) most verbose, put out every message.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)